# Explicit solution of ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I try to solve this equation $y'=\sqrt{y^2+x^2}$ by letting $u=y/x$ but this dosn't help. any suggetions? thanks

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that there exists a closed form solution of this ODE?

Comment: no, but I try to find it, is there any theorem to ensure the existence of a closed solution?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $y'=(xu)'=u+xu'$ and you have an ODE for $u$.

Comment: thanks for the hint sit,  can't separat the two parts du and dx to integrat them.

Comment: this is what I got, I couldn't separate the $u$ and the $x$.$$x\frac{{du}}{{dx}} + u = x\sqrt {1 + {u^2}} $$